# objdump showing long addresses after the linking

Tags: linux, nasm, ld, elf, memory-address

I wrote a simple little program in nasm (linux) :

[image: nasm program]

using the command `nasm -f elf32 -o file.o file.asm`to generate the object file.

When using `objdump -M intel -d file.o` I get this result :

[image: objdump]

I see that the addresses shown by `objdump` are reasonable, but when I do the compile to generate the executable code with the command `ld -m elf_i386 -o executable file.o` ; I get the followwing result by using objdump on the executable file :

[image]

Questions :

1. Why did the addresses became this long, although, the executable file is very small (500 bytes at most).
2. On what does addresses point to, I am sure that it doesn't point in the memory, because the program is not charged yet.
3. Are they relative or absolut addresses ?? If relative, then relative to what ?? and if absolute, how can they be absolute and the program isn't charged yet in the memory.

I am really sorry if this question seems stupid for some of you, but I really need to understand this, it will help me a lot in my project.

Answer (score 0):

> Why did the addresses became this long, although, the executable file is very small (500 bytes at most).

Because the default load address for i386 Linux is `0x8048000`. That address has absolutely nothing to with how large or small your program is. You can change it to some other address with e.g. `-Ttext-segment=0x...000` linker flag.

> On what does addresses point to, I am sure that it doesn't point in the memory

It points to address where the kernel *will* load your executable before passing control to it. This is also known as "linked at" address. You can look at `readelf -l a.out` to see what `PT_LOAD` segments are present in your binary, and where in memory they will be loaded.

> Are they relative or absolut addresses

Absolute.

Comment: I thought that Linux uses relative addresses !! What if I charge both programs that have theses addresses, where would they be ??!!